# Matlab Nested Classes, Reference to object of the same class from within

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create a tree class in matlab for creation of a decision tree. When I try to run this script, the first time it runs through the code, I can see that it arrived at a favorable value of F, and V. However, after the part of initialization of new nodes for left and right, even my current object is empty. How do I correctly nest a reference to the same class within the class such that they do not interfere with each other

```
classdef dtree
properties (Access = public) 
    MaxDepth;
    CurrentDepth;
    Features;
    Left;
    Right;
    F;
    V;
end
  methods
      function this=dtree(md, cd, nf, Xtrain, Ytrain)
        % Now the real initialization begins
        this.MaxDepth = md
        this.CurrentDepth = cd;
        this.Features = nf;
        this.train(Xtrain, Ytrain);
      end

      function s = gini(dt, Labels)
        s = 1;
        s = s - (sum(Labels > 0.0) ./ numel(Labels)) ^ 2;
        s = s - (sum(Labels < 0.0) ./ numel(Labels)) ^ 2;
    end

    function train(dt, Xtrain, Ytrain)
        if (size(unique(Ytrain)) == 1 | dt.CurrentDepth > dt.MaxDepth)
            return;
        end

        minGINI = Inf;
        minF = 0;
        minV = Inf;
        for i = dt.Features
            for n = 1:size(Xtrain, 1)
                idx = Xtrain(:, i) > Xtrain(n, i);
                GINI = dt.gini(Ytrain(idx)) + dt.gini(Ytrain(~idx));
                if GINI < minGINI
                    minGINI = GINI;
                    minF = i;
                    minV = Xtrain(n, i);
                end
            end
        end
        dt.F = minF
        dt.V = minV
        lIdx = Xtrain(:, dt.F) > Xtrain(dt.V, dt.F);
        dt.Left = dtree(dt.MaxDepth, dt.CurrentDepth + 1, dt.Features,Xtrain(lIdx, :), Ytrain(lIdx))
        dt.Right = dtree(dt.MaxDepth, dt.CurrentDepth + 1, dt.Features, Xtrain(~lIdx, :), Ytrain(~lIdx));
     end
  end
```

end

ans = dtree(1, 1, [2, 5 ,6], XTrain, YTrain);

During execution, 
  dtree with properties:

```
    MaxDepth: 1
CurrentDepth: 1
    Features: [4 5 2]
        Left: []
       Right: []
           F: 5
           V: 7
```

After Execution, when I type ans
ans =

dtree with properties:

```
    MaxDepth: 1
CurrentDepth: 1
    Features: [4 5 2]
        Left: []
       Right: []
           F: []
           V: []
```

Which is an empty object prior to running train.

Answer (score 0):

When you deal with class methods, you need to explicitly pass and return the object

```
function this = dtree(...)
   this = this.train(...)
end

function dt = train(dt, XTrain, YTrain)
...
end
```

If you don't do this, the reference to the object you have will not be updated. You always need to update the reference in Matlab!